# update NuGet local server

Tags: nuget, nuget-server, nugetgallery

I have a local NuGet server & NuGet gallery both in version 2.2

I want to update them to 2.8.1, without loosing all my packages and changes I made in the website.

Is there anyway to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make a copy of the code/service/web.config files that you have now as a backup. Then open the manage nuget packages dialog, go to update tab, and then click Update All.

If NuGet detect that the package's files have been modified, it will pop up an File Conflict Dialog to ask you if your current files (such as code files) etc. wanted to be overwritten, just answer No to preserver your original files.